# OS Label at System Boot Menu

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I have two disks in the same computer and both have installed Win7 (for easier transition purposes). Now, for the time being (a week or two), I will customize the new installation and when I am satisfied with the setup, I will format the old disk.

Now, during the boot, the two options in boot menu are

- Windows 7
- Windows 7

(I don't use any third-party boot loader.)

Is there any way to change the name of these labels, e.g. set them to "Win7 (old)" and "Win7 (new)"?

This is not a must, since I can definitely remember a binary choice, but I was always curious as to where this label can be set (if it can be set, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BCDEDIT - Boot Configuration Data Store Editor**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx

The Bcdedit.exe command-line tool modifies the boot configuration data store.
The boot configuration data store contains boot configuration parameters and
controls how the operating system is booted. These parameters were previously
in the Boot.ini file (in BIOS-based operating systems) or in the nonvolatile
RAM entries (in Extensible Firmware Interface-based operating systems). You can
use Bcdedit.exe to add, delete, edit, and append entries in the boot
configuration data store.

Comment: That being said, `bcdedit` isn't exactly easy to use :)

Comment: Nope, but I have found this interesting utility. Still haven't actually tried it, but there it goes. It's called EasyBCD and it can be D/L from http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1